# FFMPEG: from jpg to avi it's ok, but with bad size and quality

Tags: ffmpeg, size, jpeg, avi

I have six .jpg images with a size 350x400 (WxH).
I want to turn them into an avi file of a good quality (but not too heavy) and with same dimensions

I'm doing:

```
/var/www/html/folder/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -r 0.5 -i myfolder/434420image%05d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 -s qcif -r 0.5 myfolder/434420img_tmp.avi
```

And I'm having the avi file, but with a size of 127x142 and with a terrible resolution.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you change frame size with `-s qcif`, test `-vcodec mjpeg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-vcodec copy` in the hope that it correctly sets the fourcc in the AVI header to the one used by MJPEG.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, but don't know why adding -vcodec copy crashes it all, meaning it does not turn the images to avi.. Any other ideas? Thanks again